# Fetching from an API and mapping into select in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am fetching this data using `axios` and I want to map the names from this `object` whose `status` is `"COMPLETED"` into a React `select` menu.  How do I do it?

The response which is shown in `success.data` is given below.

React JS code

```
console.log("teacher profile data", success.data);
```

Log output

```
teacher profile data 
{…}
​
data: (6) […]
​​
0: Object { status: "COMPLETED", _id: "606bf5d19173931121c0017c", name: "Admin1", … }
​​
1: Object { status: "PENDING", _id: "606c074e9173931121c0017f", name: "Admin3", … }
​​
2: Object { status: "PENDING", _id: "606c07a99173931121c00182", name: "Admin4", … }
​​
3: Object { status: "COMPLETED", _id: "606c22129173931121c00184", name: "priyanka", … }
​​
4: Object { status: "COMPLETED", _id: "606c22369173931121c00186", name: "teacher1", … }
​​
5: Object { status: "PENDING", _id: "606c22619173931121c00188", name: "teacher2", … }
```

Lets's say I am saving this in a state `teachersData` and I want to map names in the `option` here. How do I go about it?  How should I store this names from this object whose status is completed in the state?

```
<Form.Control as="select" defaultValue="Choose..."  
onChange={ e => setField('teachers', e.target.value) }>
{teachersData.map((x, i) => {        
 <option>
    </option>
      </Form.Control>

})}
```

Comment: Edited it. Was missing the point and proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what package `Form.Control` comes from.  I am assuming [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/).  I'm also not sure where this `setField` function comes from.

> Lets's say I am saving this in a state `teachersData` and I want to map names in the `option` here. How do I go about it? How should I store this names from this object whose status is completed in the state?

You only want to have one list of teachers in state because you don't want duplicated data.  It is up to you whether you want to store the complete list from your `axios` request and filter it later or if you want to filter the list before saving it to state.  It depends on whether this component does anything other than render this `select` where it would need to access the `"PENDING"` teachers.

Let's say that you save the whole array and then filter it later.

```
const [teachers, setTeachers] = useState([]);

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
      const success = axios.get("/somepath");
      setTeachers(success.data);
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Then your `select` would look like this.  Do you want to call `setField` with the teacher's `name` or `_id`?  The one that you want should be the `value` property of the `option`.

```
<Form.Control
    as="select"
    defaultValue="Choose..."
    onChange={(e) => setField("teachers", e.target.value)}
>
    {teachers
        // filter to only completed teachers
        .filter((teacher) => teacher.status === "COMPLETED")
        // render an option for each teacher
        .map((teacher) => (
            <option
                // map needs a unique key, so use the teacher id
                key={teacher._id}
                // this will be e.target.value if this option is selected
                value={teacher._id}
            // print the teacher name as the option text
            >
                {teacher.name}
            </option>
        ))}
</Form.Control>
```